# Filter a recycleview using searchview and search suggestions and voice search

Tags: android, listview, search

[Android general search functionality](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchSuggestions) seems to have nice system support for showing search suggestions like recent query suggestions and custom suggestions, in addition to voice search.

This framework requires one to declare a search activity. That activity gets the query in an intent, and presents search results to a ListView.

I have two questions on this:

1- I want to do the search in the current activity (I have a searchview on appbar). So, will that activity be restarted? That would be weird. Should I send to an unvisible activity and get results back? Is that possible?

2- Can I use RecyclerView instead of ListView? I thought ListView is deprecated in favour of RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to do the search in the current activity (I have a searchview
>   on appbar). So, will that activity be restarted?

No. (if you implement searching right of course)

> Can I use RecyclerView instead of ListView? I thought ListView is
>   deprecated in favour of RecyclerView.

Yes, you can use `RecyclerView`

Basically what you have to do to implement searching in `RecyclerView` you will have to create a public method in your adapter class with parameter of `List` of your data class something like this:

```
 public void setFilter(ArrayList<Items> ItemList){
    Items = new ArrayList<>();
    Items.addAll(ItemList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  //Items will be your custom data class
}
```

Then in your `Activity` where you want to implement searching after implementing `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` interface and overriding methods `onQueryTextSubmit` and `onQueryTextChange` in `onQueryTextChange` you can do something like this:

```
 @Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    newText = newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<Items> ItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Items Item : Items) //Items your data class containg data provided to adapter
    {
        String name = Item.getTitle().toLowerCase(); // getTitle or getName dependes what you have in Item class
        if(name.contains(newText))
            ItemArrayList.add(Item);
    }
    adapter.setFilter(ItemArrayList); // adapter will be instance of adapter class
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is OK, but how can I add suggestions and voice search?

Comment: I would try with creating new inner class in adapter and extending `Filter` and for the voice search, maybe just to try after converting voice to string call `onQueryTextChange` providing converted word as parametar.